# Should I choose high time complexity data structures or high space complexity data structures for efficient methods?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I have to choose between two data structures, ArrayList and LinkedList.
I have two operations op_one, op_two.

If I choose ArrayList -
  I will end up with

```
for op_one ------ O(n), and at maximum n re-allocations
for op_two ------ O(1), and at maximum n re-allocations
```

If I choose LinkedList  -
  I will end up with

```
for op_one ------ O(n), and zero re-allocations
for op_two ------ O(n), and zero re-allocations
```

I will be storing millions of comparable elements. And I will be doing both the operations equally likely. Which one should I choose.

Comment: Is it not possible to let the operation create the List?

Comment: I understand you are counting re-allocations (shifting items in an array when deleting or inserting an item) as memory-complexity, but that re-allocation is time complexity. Therefore op_two for ArrayList might be O(n) and **not** O(1).
Somehow I understood the question about which time complexity was better/worse

Comment: Furthermore, if each re-allocation means moving N items. N re-allocations mean O(N^2) time complexity. Please clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you time them together and a realistic way and see which is faster.  If they are not significantly different I would use the approach you believe is simplest.

While the order of ArrayList and LinkedLIst are the same for space, the ArrayList is much smaller.

All the same clarity is usually the most important unless you know you have a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

*(Question first understood as time complexity disregarding space. Request for clarifications made in comments)*

I would use ArrayList (over LinkedList), not only because time complexity, but because it is simpler and it doesn't build a new node for each item.

Note overall complexity will be O(n) in either case: For ArrayList an O(n) + O(1), or prob*O(n) + (1-prob)*O(1) will be in the order of O(n).

Given equal complexity ( O(n) ), then you should find out actual execution time, or chose the easier to implement or maintain.

Comment: I think you mean ArrayList doesn't build a new node for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that on modern architectures memory bandwidth is often the bottleneck. Sometimes computing a result is hence faster than storing and reading pre-computed values. In other words, computational complexity should be considered together with memory complexity. I would keep the memory usage small if the computations are not expensive and can work within the cache.

But in the end, you will have to test...